# BootHoleDetection script claims Ubuntu 22 signed-shim is vulnerable to BootHole problem

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

https://eclypsium.com/2020/07/29/theres-a-hole-in-the-boot/
Description of BootHole vulnerability from July, 2020.

The check script is from eclypsium,
https://github.com/eclypsium/BootHole
the folks who reported BootHole two years ago. I'm surprised that it is still an issue on Jammy (22.04). My laptop has been running Ubuntu for years, so perhaps a clean install might be different.

The script works by generating the problem certificate as a TXT file. It then uses sbverify to check

sbverify --cert /tmp/ubuntu_cert.txt /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

Signature verification OK

That is claiming that my shimx64.efi was signed by the OLD Microsoft certificate which should have been retired.

Is this true? Is Ubuntu still using the old Microsoft certificate? How can I check which certificate signed my shim?

Comment: The title says you are running Ubuntu Core 22 is this correct?

Comment: @David Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
I am not sure of the definition for Ubuntu Core. An Internet search suggests that it is used for IoT and embedded systems. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo laptop.